# PFObject Subclassing: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform, subclassing

I'm trying to create a custom class for PFObject (Subclassing), which seems to work fine, but when I try to convert/use the custom class object, as a regular PFObject, It messes up. Here's what I'm trying to do.

**First I have created the Custom Class named** `NewPFObject` **for testing reasons.**

**NOTICE: I AM calling** `NewPFObject.registerSubclass()` **in the AppDelegate before setting the Application Id.**

```
class NewPFObject: PFObject, PFSubclassing {

    static func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "NewPFObject"
    }

    override init(className:String) {
        super.init(className: className)
    }

}
```

**Then I have this method that's using it to make Async calls more easy and fluid:**

```
func GetAsyncObjects(query:STARCQuery, doNext: (dataObjects:[NewPFObject]) -> ()) {
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (newObjects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            doNext(dataObjects: newObjects as! [NewPFObject])
        }

    }
}
```

**And finally, I have the use-case, where the error happens.**

```
let query:PFQuery = PFQuery.init(className: "MyCustomClassInParse")

GetAsyncObjects(query) { (dataObjects) -> () in

    if(dataObjects.count > 0) {
        for customObject in dataObjects {
            //Do something with customObject data
        }
    }

}
```

The error at the use-case is the same as the title:

> **fatal errror:** NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type

And It happens on the final block of code, on the line where I use the `dataObjects` Array in the `for` loop.

When trying to cast it multiple times makes XCode say that It's redundant to do so, and It doesn't make a difference when actually running the code. Same error.

I've literally tried everything, and every post about PFSubclassing and this error on Stackoverflow, can't seem to find the solution, so I hope someone Is willing to help me out!

Thanks!

Comment: You are using `NewPFObject` then suddenly switch to `MyCustomClassInParse` is that a typo or are you really using two different class names?  Have you used the debugger to look at `dataObjects` and see what is inside the NSArray?

Comment: @Paulw11, the "MyCustomClassInParse" is the actual class in the Parse cloud. NewPFObject is the Physical class on the device (The Script). The dataObjects contains PFObject's as a Subclass of NewPFObject, that's why I'm confused.

Comment: @Paulw11, I'm pretty sure that the PFQuery doesn't have anything to do with the PFObject or the NewPFObject.

Comment: The class name returned by `parseClassName` must be the name of the class in Parse. This is how the framework maps the returned data to your custom subclass. Since it doesn't match you are just going to get an array of PFObject

Comment: @Paulw11 Wow. That is actually it. You are completely right. But how would I go about making this work universally / dynamic with any Parse Class then?

Comment: @Paulw11 With only 1 Physical Class (NewPFObject) instead of creating a class for every cloud-class. If you get me?

Comment: You have to create a PFSubclassing class for each one. That is the point. By creating the PFSubclassing class you can then map attributes to properties so you can say `obj.name` instead of `obj["name"]`. As each class has different attributes you need different PFSubclassing classes. If you want just one class you already have it; PFObject.

Comment: Good point @Paulw11 .. Really good point.. I appreciate your help. You wanna put that into an answer that I can accept? :)

Comment: Will do shortly; it is a bit painful to do on the iPad I am currently using...

Comment: Well that is very true ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you return from `parseClassName` must match the class name that is defined in Parse.com, so in your case, `parseClassName` would need to return *MyCustomClassInParse*

This enables the Parse framework to match the `PFSubclassing` class to the Parse.com class and return the appropriate object. If there is no match then you will just get plain-old `PFObject` instances, which is why you get a runtime error when you try to downcast.